# Why does my haskell program keep running out of memory ?

Tags: haskell, file-io, functional-programming

Hello fellow coders. 
So i decided to rewrite some of my old scripts i had lying around in haskell just because i need the practice and i like the language. So here i am trying to filter a huge file (around 1.7 GB) , cut the lines of no interest and write the remaining stuff in another file.

I thought that haskell's lazy nature would be ideal for this but the code keeps running out of memory too soon. The previous versions (c# or Python) had a read line -> write line approach but i tried a different approach here. Should i just rewrite the code to mirror the previous version or am i missing something.

So this is the function in charge of the original file filtering:

```
getLines :: FilePath -> IO [[String]]
getLines path = do
    text<-readFile path
    let linii=lines text
    let tokens = map words linii
    let filtrate=[x|x<-tokens,length x>7,isTimeStamp (x!!0),isDiagFrame x]
    return filtrate
```

this one is in charge of writing one line at a time in the new file (altho i tried to use writeFile dirrectly and failed miserably :) :

```
writeLines ::Handle->[[String]]->IO ()
writeLines handle linii = do
                    let linie=concat $ intersperse " " (head  linii)
                    hPutStrLn handle linie
                    if length linii > 0     then
                                    writeLines handle  (tail linii)
                                        else
                                    print "Writing complete..."
```

and these 2 are the main function and another one in charge of geting the handle and passing it around :

```
writeTheFile :: FilePath->FilePath->IO ()
writeTheFile inf outf = do
handle<-openFile outf WriteMode
linii<-getLines inf
writeLines handle linii
print "Write Complete"


main = do
arg<-getArgs
if length arg/=2    then
    print "Use like this : trace_pars [In_File] [Out_File] !"
                    else 
    writeTheFile (arg!!0) (arg!!1)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated...thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is in this line:

```
                    if length linii > 0     then
```

You are computing the length of your list of lines. This means that the whole list of lines has to be loaded for it to be counted. Which means that the whole file that you're reading needs to be loaded into memory. Not good!

The solution is to use `if not . null $ linii then` instead. The `null` function checks whether a list is empty (which only forces the first line of the list to be loaded), and `not` behaves like you'd expect.

If you would like a more idiomatic version of `writeLines` (Note the use of `FilePath` instead of `Handle`):

```
writeLines :: FilePath -> [[String]] -> IO ()
writeLines filename = writeFile filename . unlines . map unwords
```

This function is the same as:

```
writeLines filename lines =
  writeFile filename mergedFile
  where
    mergedFile = unlines mergedLines
    mergedLines = map unwords lines
```

`unlines` is the same as `intercalate "\n"`, and `unwords` is the same as `intercalate " "`. `intercalate x` is the same as `concat . intersperse x`.

I think that this should be enough information for you to understand what's going on.

Comment: thanks man....the condition was indeed the problem.....will try to do it without recursion next